# stanford CoreNLP Tool (Constituency Parser) for German doesn't work

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm using stanford CoreNLP Tool especially Constituency Parser for German.
I'm working in command line.

This is the command that I used:

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props StanfordCoreNLP-german.properties -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse -parse.model edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/germanSR.ser.gz -file Test.txt -outputFormat xml
```

Then I got followings:

```
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger - Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/german/german-hgc.tagger ... done [4.2 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator parse 
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/germanSR.ser.gz ... done [4.8 sec].

Processing file /home/students/park/Desktop/SWP/s_COREnlp_370/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31/Test.txt ... writing to /home/students/park/Desktop/SWP/s_COREnlp_370/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31/Test.txt.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator.finishSentence(ParserAnnotator.java:309)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator.doOneSentence(ParserAnnotator.java:267)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.SentenceAnnotator.annotate(SentenceAnnotator.java:102)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotationPipeline.annotate(AnnotationPipeline.java:75)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.annotate(StanfordCoreNLP.java:605)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.annotate(StanfordCoreNLP.java:615)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.processFiles(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1167)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.processFiles(StanfordCoreNLP.java:948)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.run(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1256)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.main(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1326)
```

What is the reason of this problem?
How can I solve it?

The command did work for English.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you get the latest version of Stanford CoreNLP 3.7.0.  I think this bug has been fixed, so you should download it again.  When I run on a sample sentence with the latest code there is no NullPointer issue.